# GET byte array from SQL Server parameter in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, byte, varbinary

I am trying to get a byte array from my SQL Server parameter. I get the data from SQL Server like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image1", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Size = 5000000;
cmd.Parameters["@Image1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string str = cmd.Parameters["@Image1"].Value.ToString();
```

I get the value `System.Byte[]` in string however I would need the whole byte array that I could store it as an image.

How would I do it using `.Value` returns an object would I convert that object to byte array?

Comment: Had you tried this: `string str = cmd.Parameters["@Image1"].Value as byte[];`?

Comment: The fact that you get `System.Byte[]` when you call the `ToString` method tells you the value is already of the type you expect. All you need to do is assign the type-casted value to a variable.

Comment: oh ok that makes more sense didn't really know you can convert it that easily. Ill Try it out

Answer (score 2):

You might be overthinking this:

```
byte[] imageArray = (byte[])cmd.Parameters["@Image1"].Value;
```

EDIT: Casted right hand side. Thanks JuanR.

Comment: @JuanR Can you explain why? We're already told `cmd.Parameters["@Image1"].Value` is of type `System.Byte[]`. This is for my own learning.

Comment: It's because of type checking at compile time. The compiler will tell you it cannot **implicitly** convert the type. The `Value` property is of type `object`. You are assigning it to a variable of type `byte[]`. The compiler has no way of knowing that the object is in fact of that type so it is forcing you to perform a cast for consistency.

Comment: I see thanks for the explanation. I've casted to `byte[]` in my answer.

Comment: +1 from me. I actually like this approach better as opposed to `as byte[]` since that one results is a `null` object if it cannot cast it, which can be misleading at runtime.